# Not Able to Create React app (npx create-react-app myapp/ npm install/npm i express)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, proxy

I am using react app from many days, but few days ago it has stop working.npx create-react-app myapp is not working for me. I have tried using proxy and then unset the proxy and tried again. But no difference. npx create-react-app myapp/ npm install/npm i express --> This all command are not working for me. Given below is the error coming ....

[image]

I have tried using different ways but none has worked for me.
Please someone tell how to run this command --> npx create-react-app myapp/ npm install/npm i express

Comment: Here are something you can try. update npm version or nodejs version. you can try a wrapper like vite or a framework like nextjs instead of create-react-app. as you might know that the new updated offical react documentation react.dev suggests that React is a library. It lets you put components together, but it doesn’t prescribe how to do routing and data fetching. To build an entire app with React, we recommend a full-stack React framework like Next.js or Remix. so try nextjs.